# A normal (?) subgroup in SL(2,F)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm probably doing something very stupid here, but I got in a spat with a professor today because we couldn't figure something out.

The subgroup of upper triangular matrices in SL(2,F) certainly shouldn't be normal, for example $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ conjugates $\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &\beta \\ 
 0& \alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^{-1} &0 \\ 
 -\beta& \alpha
\end{bmatrix}$

But on the other hand, if we take an arbitrary matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ in SL(2,F) and directly compute its product with an upper triangular matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &\beta \\ 
 0& \alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$, we get: $$\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &\beta \\ 
 0& \alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
d &-b \\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}=$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a\alpha &a\beta+ b\alpha^{-1}\\ 
c\alpha & c\beta+d\alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}$$ $$=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha ad-\alpha bc & \beta ad+\alpha^{-1}bd-\beta bc-\alpha^{-1}bd\\ 
-\alpha ac+\alpha ac & -\beta ca-\alpha^{-1}cb+\beta ac+\alpha^{-1} ad
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha (ad-bc) & \beta (ad-bc)\\ 
0 & \alpha^{-1} (ad-bc)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &\beta \\ 
 0& \alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

So what am I doing wrong? This ought to be real obvious, right?

Comment: Something went very wrong in the multiplication that produced the first matrix on the second to last line.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the second line, rather than computing
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a\alpha &a\beta+ b\alpha^{-1}\\ 
c\alpha & c\beta+d\alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}$$

you instead computed
$$\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a\alpha &a\beta+ b\alpha^{-1}\\ 
c\alpha & c\beta+d\alpha^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

This would explain why you ended up where you started.

Comment: I have much shame

Comment: It happens to the best of us...